# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3.h

Tags: c, sqlite

I am trying to use sqlite3 in my Eclipse C project, I have added sqlite3.h and its address: /usr/include/ to linker, but still get this error message:

```
make all 
Building target: SQLiteTest
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -L/usr/include/ -o "SQLiteTest"  ./hello.o   -lsqlite3.h 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3.h
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [SQLiteTest] Error 1
```

I guess I have to add it to compiler as well, have tried many ways, but none of them worked.

Thanks for help

Comment: `sqlite3.h` is a header, not a library... why would you pass a header to the linker? I think you should maybe look at some C tutorials

Comment: Try `-lsqlite3` instead. As mentioned, `.h` is a specific (header) file, completely unrelated (from a process standpoint) to linking.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ if it is a C project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling and linking C programs:

- the `-I/some/where/include` option is used to specify where headers (*include files*) are found,
- the `-L/some/where/lib` option is used to specify where libraries are found,
- the `-lname` option is used to say "link with the library `libname.so` or `libname.a`"

The suffixes on libraries vary by platform — choose from `.sl`, `.sa`, `.dll`, `.lib`, `.dylib`, `.bundle`, to name but a few alternative extensions.

The `-L/usr/include` option is unlikely to be correct.  Headers are stored in `/usr/include`, and not libraries.  Changing that to `-I/usr/include` is unnecessary; the compiler will search in `/usr/include` anyway.  If the `sqlite3.h` header is in `/usr/include`, it will be found without options.  If it is somewhere else, like perhaps `/usr/local/include` or `/opt/sqlite3/include`, then you may well need to specify `-I/usr/local/include` or `-I/opt/sqlite3/include` on the command line.  In each case, you might also need `-L/usr/local/lib` or `-L/opt/sqlite3/lib` as well.  (Note that your compiler might, but probably won't, search in `/usr/local` automatically.)

As noted in the comments, you would not specify `-lsqlite3.h` on the command line.  It would mean that there was a library such as `libsqlite3.h.so` somewhere on your system, which is an implausible name.  Most likely, you should just specify `-lsqlite3` on the linking command line.